# How to make numeralJS output 'no decimal' and with a decimal point on the same variable?

Tags: javascript, formatting, numbers

I'm working with the very handy, crafty, and cool JS library, [NumeralJS](http://numeraljs.com/)

I went into their examples and docs but I couldn't find an answer to something I have in mind, so, I'm posting here hoping to get a quick answer:

basically, if I have a variable, say `x`, and `x` can have two types on numbers in it: a whole number, and a number with a decimal point.

say, if `x`'s value is a flat 10, the numeralJS output on HTML should look like "10".

So, when `x`'s value is a 3.67144, the output I wanted will be "3.7".

But here's my dilemma:

When I use something like this,

```
var x = 10;
return numeral(x).format('0');
// I get "10"... cool
```

but,

```
var x = 3.67144;
return numeral(x).format('0');
// I get "4", when I want 3.7 :(
```

then, I use this,

```
var x = 10;
return numeral(x).format('0.0');
// I get "10.0"... not what I want :(
```

and,

```
var x = 3.67144;
return numeral(x).format('0.0');
// I get "3.7"... which was okay, but you know...
```

So, yeah.  Any ideas, good folks? (Should I involve some complicated conditional ninjutsu on this? Probably?)

Answer (score 3):

... Nevermind...

```
var x = 3.67144; //or 10
return numeral(x).format('0.[0]');
```

Worked like a freaky voodoo. I was playing around and stumbled on it.